# What happens if you add a property to a function using the object style?

Tags: javascript

Strangely, the following code gives no error in the lastest Chrome browser:

```
function func(){
    x:1
}
func();
```

What happened exactly?
(I am not trying to add a property to the function, I know how to do that using `func.property` or `arguments.callee.property`)

Update: If `x:1` is a `labeled statement`, then

```
function func(){
    1
}
```

is considered a valid function. What is `1` here doing? Is it just ignored? Is it a statement, expression or something else?

Comment: Your title conflicts with the body of your post. `"What happens if you add a property..."` - `"I am not trying to add a property..."`. Perhaps a title referencing a question about this specific syntax would be more appropriate.

Comment: The later function is valid because a statement with just a number is valid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your line

```
x:1
```

is a [labeled statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label).

> The **labeled statement** can be used with [break](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break) or [continue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue) statements. It is prefixing a statement with an identifier which you can refer to.

[Example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue#Using_continue_with_a_label):

```js
var i = 0;
var j = 8;

checkiandj: while (i < 4) {
    console.log("i: " + i);
    i += 1;

    checkj: while (j > 4) {
        console.log("j: " + j);
        j -= 1;

        if ((j % 2) == 0)
            continue checkj;
        console.log(j + " is odd.");
    }
    console.log("i = " + i);
    console.log("j = " + j);
}
```

Comment: @evolutionxbox, please read the referenced links. a label can be *Any JavaScript identifier that is not a reserved word.*

Comment: So `function func(){
    1
}` is correct? What is `1` here? A statement? A declaration?or it is simply ignored by the JS engine?

Comment: Oh god. I had blanked out that javascrippt had goto!

Comment: @J.Joe, its an expression.

Comment: an expression? even there is no `;` at the end? I thought `function func(){ 1 }` should give syntax errors.

Comment: @J.Joe, please remember the [ASI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi)

Comment: Right. The x:1 line... Now I see.